# Query only fails in my app, but works fine in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT EquipmentNumber, P.AreaCode AS AreaCode, EquipmentType, EquipDsc FROM MajorEquipment ME
 INNER JOIN PlantAreaCodes P ON ME.PACId = P.PACId;
```

And it works fine in MySQL, but when I try to use it in my app, I get the error "Unkown column "ME.PACId in 'ON clause'.

I find it especially strange that it only fails in my app. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Are you connecting with a different user?

Comment: @nvoigt No, I have been using the same user in this app constantly. No issues with the connection, or any other query, only this one.

Comment: I meant are you using the same user to connect *in your app* and in MySql client?

Comment: @nvoigt Yes. That is also what I meant. The username and password for MySQL is set in the app, so that never changes.

Comment: @Ben check directly using the Tablename instead of Alias name and see if it works ?

Comment: @Peru Found the problem... because I was using strings, I didn't leave a space between `MajorEquipment ME` `INNER JOIN`. Instead I had `MajorEquipment MEINNER JOIN`. Silliest mistake I couls have ever made

Answer (score 0):

The issue was much simpler than I had expected; because I was inputting these through strings, I had the query like this:

```
"Line 1" +
"Line 2";
```

Which printed like this: `Line 1Line 2`. I didn't leave a space at the end of line one or at the beginning of line 2. What I needed was this:

```
"Line 1" +
" Line 2";
```

So the problem was occurring when it was reading the alias. It though I had used the alias `MajorEquipment MEINNER JOIN`, rather than `MajorEquipment ME INNER JOIN`